# "org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException:" Error occurred while running jmeter

Tags: jmeter, redhat

I have recorded reports in my application and running scripts for `JMeter 3.0` in RedHat server. But, a `ConnectionClosedException` has error occurred as shown below

```
Error:
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:268)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:186)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:73)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:150)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1779)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:412)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:400)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Error: Number format exception for input string: "" error showing in Assertion result window.

[image]

Does anyone know a solution for this exception?

Comment: What is your request ? What are your headers ?

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://apache.spd.co.il//jmeter/binaries/) later version of Jmeter, in Jmeter 3.1 there were [improvements](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html#Improvements) with HTTP:

> Since version 3.1, HTTP Request is able when using HttpClient4
>   (default) implementation to handle responses bigger than 2147483647
>   Bytes, that is 2GB